# If email exists return error else add php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to write a script that does the following. Takes a users email and added's it to a database however if the users email already exists it rejects.

```
<?
require_once('includes/db.php'); 

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['email']); 

$dupesql = "SELECT * FROM emails where (email = '$email')";
$duperaw = mysqli_query($link, $dupesql);


if(int mysql_num_rows($duperaw) > 0){
     echo 'Error already in there';
}
else {
$sql = "INSERT INTO emails(email)
    VALUES('$email')";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql); 

header('Location: poll/poll.php');
}


// close mysql
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: The code is pretty procedural, but it should be ok like this. You also want to use PDO and just make a nicer prepared statement. That way it's easier to escape your input into the query. Last note; the connection will never be closed, because the `header()` will lead the page away to `poll/poll.php`.

Comment: (`mysql_num_rows`) Mixing `mysqli_` with `mysql_` won't get you much results, which is the main problem here. Use `mysqli_num_rows` instead.

Comment: Hi Allendar, Thank you for your reply, currently im getting the following error syntax error, unexpected 'mysql_num_rows' (T_STRING) and I'm pretty stumped I've been trying to get this working for about an hour now. I agree the code is very procedural but I'm currently learning php so I wanted to keep it simple.

Comment: @Fred-ii-Thank you very much I knew it was something silly on my part. Allendar thank you for your help as well please disregard my last :)

Comment: You're welcome David. Let's close this question properly then with [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20275910/1415724) ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not let mysql take care of it? When you already want `email` to be unique, then define an unique index for `email` :

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX email_index ON emails (email)
```

now you only have to check if any rows has been affected after insert :

```
if (mysqli_affected_rows()>0) {
  //success, email inserted
} else {
  // rejected
}
```

By that you'll spare a call to the database and make the code more simplistic, imho.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$mysqli->real_query('INSERT INTO '.$table.' ('.$cols.') VALUES ('.$vals.')');
```

Comment: put the value for your name of table eg. email_list_table, name of cols , eg. Email and email value example@mail.com

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as follow:

```
$dupesql = "SELECT * FROM emails where email = '$email'";
$duperaw = mysqli_query($link, $dupesql);


if(mysql_num_rows($duperaw)==1){
 echo 'Error already in there';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `mysqli_` with `mysql_` which is the main problem here.

Use `mysqli_num_rows` instead of `mysql_num_rows`

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix mysqli() and mysql(). 
And remove **int** error casting.

```
//...
if(mysqli_num_rows($duperaw) > 0){
     echo 'Error already in there';
}
//...
```